# Unable to understand how useCallback prevents re-renders

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

I am learning about `useCallback` from React's Beta [docs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nec41u?file=Shipping.tsx). I re-created the example shown in the docs but I am unable to prevent any re-rendering by using `useCallback` and `memo`.

If you click on any product, the `Shipping` component is getting re-rendered anyway (check `console.log`'s output in the debugger console) even after using `memo` and passing a prop which is cached using `useCallback`.

What am I doing wrong?

Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nec41u?file=Shipping.tsx

Answer (score 1):

If you click on a product, then the productId changes. Since productId is in the dependency array of useCallback, it will cause the handleSubmit to be created again. And since handleSubmit, the props of Shipping changes, the component is rerendered. If you removed the productId from the array, then Shipping would not longer rerendered, but in that case the function will work incorrectly.